# How to customize the loss function using Wasserstein distance in Pytorch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch

I am new to using Pytorch. I have two sets of observational data `Y` and `X`, probably having different dimensions. My task is to train a function `g` such that the distribution distance between `g(X)` and `Y` is the smallest. I would like to impose the Wasserstein distance as the loss function. Is it possible to customize the loss function using the Wasserstein distance in Pytorch? If not, is it possible to write in Keras? When both methods do not work, what should be the alternative solution?